# Django-Postgres: how to group by DATE a datetime field with timezone enabled

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I am having this problem with prostgresql and django:

I have a lot of events that were created on a certain date at a certain time which is stored in a datetime field `created` .

- I want to have aggregations based on the date part of the `created` field. The simplest examples is: `how many event are in each day of this month?`.
- The `created` field is timezone aware. So the result should change depending on the timezone the user is in. For example if you created 2 events at 23:30 UTC time on 2017-10-02 if you view them from UTC-1 you should see them on 3rd of October at 00:30 and the totals should add for the 3rd.

I am struggling to find a solution to this problem that works with a lot of data. So doing for each day and SQL statement is not an option. I want something that translates into:

```
SELECT count(*) from table GROUP BY date
```

Now I found a solution for the first part of the problem:

```
from django.db import connection
truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('day', 'created')
queryset = queryset.extra({'day': truncate_date})
total_list = list(queryset.values('day').annotate(amount=Count('id')).order_by('day'))
```

Is there a way to add to this the timezone that should be used by  the date_trunc_sql function to calculate the day? Or some other function before date_trunc_sql and then chain that one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for this: [timezone aware date_trunc function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040039/timezone-aware-date-trunc-function)

However bear in mind this might conflict with how your django is configured. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: Thanks. the links were useful and i found a way to solve my problem using `date_trunc_sql` . Also the comment in this one helped. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385370/django-orm-with-date-trunk-function-and-timezones

Comment: I saw there was a connection.ops.datetime_trunc_sql function that takes the timezone as parameter but i could not make that work. Have any idea on how to do that? it was closing the connection afterwards, on the line `queryset = queryset.extra({'day': truncate_date})`

Comment: AFAIK this particular line should not invoke SQL query. I might be wrong though. One thing I'd try would be to wrap that in a transaction. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

Answer (score 1):

Django 2.2+ supports the [`TruncDate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate) database function with timezones

You can now do the following to :

```
import pytz

east_coast = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
queryset.annotate(created_date=TruncDay("created", tzinfo=east_coast))
    .values("created_date")
    .order_by("created_date")
    .annotate(count=Count("created_date"))
    .order_by("-created_date")
```